# Jquery mobile sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I have a jquery mobile header `div (data-role="header" data-position="fixed")` with two toolbars inside in a layout like this:

```
_____________________
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY|
```

and I want to reproduce the effect of WhatsApp, where scroll down **hides** toolbar `XXXXXXXX` and scroll up **shows** toolbar `XXXXXXXXXX`. Toolbar `YYYYYY` always **visible**.

By using `window.onscroll` this can be achieved by adding/removing a class with `top:-50px;` upon scroll down/scroll up.

It works, however, it works only when the page is loaded for the first time or it is reached with a link having `rel=external.` In all other cases, it is impossible to see the effect of the added class. I have also tried `.addClass("sticky").enhanceWithin()` with no effect.

Any suggestion to make this to work every time?

Here the code:

```
var didScroll = false;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = 20;

$(document).on("scroll", function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(currentScroll >= 200) {
        $("#scrollToTop").show();
    } else {
        $("#scrollToTop").hide();
    }

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - currentScroll) <= delta)
        return;

    if (currentScroll > lastScrollTop && currentScroll > navbarHeight){
        $('#PageHeader').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        if(currentScroll + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#PageHeader').removeClass('sticky').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = currentScroll;
}
```

Comment: Will you be able to post your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope my fiddle will help you out:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Lfve19u0/]
```

Ramon.